# Amazon AWS tutorials?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I was wondering if there is any tutorials for Amazon AWS, providing a step-by-step guide through setting up and hosting a simple application? E.g. a simple holiday image list application?

I understand most of the components however I cant seem to link them logically together.

I have an Amazon Free tier account, and I have signed up for the following services:
   - Amazon EC2
   - Amazon S3
   - Amazon SimpleDB
   - Amazon SNS / SQS
   - Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for Eclipse

Im confused about how to deploy an Elastic Beanstalk application, written in Java and Eclipse, through an EC2 instance etc.

Thanks greatly in advance,
U.

Comment: @Sotapanna - i know, last year I was ignorant to the cause...unfortunately I have to bail on and hope that people will ignore my posts from 2009/2010, and accept that a decent practice has been accepted....

Answer (score 9):

i found the following videos to be really useful:  http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/

start with the AWS SDK for Java video, then move on to the elastic beanstalk video where you'll deploy the SampleTravelLog webapp from within eclipse.

that should get you and end-to-end sample to play with.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried my hands at writing simple tutorials with SQS and S3 in java. Please check if they can help you a bit? I will be writing on more of AWS services. But this is what I have so far.

SQS
http://weblog4j.com/2013/03/20/working-with-amazon-simple-queue-service-using-java/

S3
http://weblog4j.com/2013/03/13/developing-java-web-application-powered-by-amazon-s3/

Listening to SQS using apache camel
http://weblog4j.com/2013/04/17/amazon-sqs-listening-to-amazon-sqs-queue-using-apache-camel/

Listening to SQS using apache camel using spring dsl
http://weblog4j.com/2013/05/14/amazon-sqs-listening-to-sqs-using-apache-camel-the-spring-dsl-way/

Answer (score 0):

Some python code  on Elastic transcode can be found at http://sateeshkblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/use-aws-elastic-transcode-to-transcode-files-with-python/

Hope it helps.